# how instance of class is creating recursively and thus causing stackoverflow error

Tags: java

Consider following 2 programs giving same error
First calss:

```
public class Testing {    
    Testing t=new Testing();        
    public static void main(String args[]){   
        testing t1=new testing();  
    }
}
```

Second class:

```
class foo{
    void baz(){
        new testing();
    }
}
public class testing {
    testing t=new testing();    
    public static void main(String args[]){
    foo f=new foo();
        f.baz();
    }       
}
```

how does above code giving following error?
 I know instance of class is creating recursively but I want to know how?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.Testing.<init>(Testing.java:4)
    at com.Testing.<init>(Testing.java:4)
```

also Why doesn't this happen if we do

```
    public class testing { 
    testing t2=new testing(); 
    testing t1=new testing(); 
    public static void main(String args[])
    {//anything}
    }
```

as t1 will require t2 object to be initalized and vice-versa?

Comment: In future, please take the time to format your code for a question, using spaces rather than tabs. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
public class Testing {    
    Testing t=new Testing();  
}
```

This is broadly the same as:

```
public class Testing {
    Testing t;

    public Testing() {
        t = new Testing();
    }
}
```

That makes the recursion clearer - the constructor is unconditionally calling itself.

Each instance of `Testing` contains a reference to another instance of `Testing`. That *needn't* be a problem - but it is here, because it's creating a *new* instance of `Testing`. So creating the "outermost" instance immediately triggers the creation of another one... which triggers the creating of another one, etc.

Your two classes aren't significantly different in that respect - creating any instance of `Testing` will cause a stack overflow.

EDIT: Regarding this code (names and formatting improved):

```
public class Testing { 
    Testing t1 = new Testing(); 
    Testing t2 = new Testing(); 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //anything
    }
}
```

*will* still throw the same exception if you try to create an instance of `Testing`. You're wrong to state that "t1 will require t2 object to be initialized" though - there's no interdependence between the variables here. Each variable initializer creates a separate object... but each of *those* objects would in turn try to create two more instances of `Testing`.

Note that an instance of `Testing` is *not* required in order to run the `main` method - but if that `main` method either calls `new Testing` directly, or calls something *else* which calls `new Testing()`, then you'll get the stack overflow.

Comment: @jon skeet `Each instance of Testing contains a reference to another instance of Testing.` How? since one instance is global and other is inside static method ( asstatic method belong to class not object).

Comment: @user980089: You have an *instance* variable inside `Testing`. Each instance of `Testing` has a `t` variable. I've edited my answer to make it even clearer.

Comment: I have edited my question, so why does'nt error occur for the code given in last.

Comment: @Jon `public class Testing {     Testing t;      public Testing() {         t = new Testing();     } } ` doesn't look correct...? as error occurs only when code has a `new Testing()` inside a method and at class level. But not in case where `new Testing()` is at class level only(or inside method only).

Comment: @user980089: What do you mean by "doesn't look correct"? That's pretty much the translation of the first code. The point is that if an instance variable is declared with an initializer which calls something, that's largely equivalent to putting that call within the constructor.

Comment: @JonSkeet If this is the case then everytime i create object at class level it should give stackoverflow error becuse it will recursively call infinitely. But this does not happen.

Comment: @user980089: It really *will* if you create an instance of the *same* class when declaring an instance variable. If you believe that's not the case, please edit your question with a short but complete program demonstrating it not happening, and I'll explain why.

Comment: @user980089: I've added more detail in my answer to your previous edit.

Comment: @Jon consider this `public class testing { testing t2=new testing(); public static void main(String args[]){//anything}` It is working fine.

Comment: @JonSkeet you are right about stating that there is no interdependence. But i want to know  `if that main method either calls new Testing directly, or calls something else which calls new Testing(), then you'll get the stack overflow.`  then why only in this case it is causing error as even otherwise it should cause error because when class level object is instatiated it should go in infinite recursion according to your previous code.

Comment: @user980089: It will only cause an error if any instances are created. Calling a static method *doesn't require an instance*. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah i know that static methods do not require instance. Do the statement `Testing t=new Tesing()` create an instance of class Testing when we run the code ? and how is instance ceated because this code does not cause erroe.

Comment: @user980089: Yes, it absolutely *will* if it's executed. Again, produce a short but *complete* program (not just "anything", but real code) which you think contradicts my assertions.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13104/discussion-between-jon-skeet-and-user980089)

Answer (score 3):

have ever thought when your program will end..it will never. It instantiates your first object while instantiating it needs to instatiates another one for the first one and so on. So your stack blows up at some time.

**First Object(needs second Object(needs third object(needs fourth object))) and it goes on..**

Comment: @Ahmed There are 2 objects one is global and other is inside a static method. So do they wait for initialization of each other? Please can you elaborate how this is happening?

Comment: 1st Case: whenever u instantiate t1 in main() method, this t1 Object will need one more object of Testing for itself(suppose its t).right ...?..now your program goes to instantiate this t...while instantiating this t it finds oh heck..!!! ..one more t is needed for this t..so it goes to instantiate  this one more new t..and it gets itself busy instantiating one more t until your stack blows up..

Comment: 2nd Case: nothing is different..the moment you start instantiating an object which needs object of its type...this problem occurs..

Comment: @Ahmed thanx for quick reply. But you said `this t1 Object will need one more object of Testing for itself` Why would it need other object?

Comment: Why doesn't this happen if we do `public class testing {
 testing t2=new testing();
 testing t1=new testing(); public static void main(String args[]){//anything}}` as t1 will require t2 and vice versa.

Comment: @user980089: No, `t1` and `t2` will each refer to separate instances of `testing`. But you'll still have a stack overflow as soon as you try to create any instances.